# Problema al exportar e importar modulos javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de importar una variable de un archivos js a otro js y me da este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**archivos.js**

```
export const hola = 5
```

**codigo.js**

```
import { hola } from './archivos.js'
```

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para mostrar lo que tienes en **./archivos.js**?

Comment: Solo tengo lo mostrado, nada más

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas encerrar la importación dentro de una etiqueta `<script type="module"></script>` de ahí el error que te aparece. Te pongo un ejemplo básico de uso:

**export.js**

```
export const hola = 'HOLA';
```

**miHTML.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="module">
     import { hola } from './export.js';     
     alert(hola);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```